# Can you disable Bundler in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

It causes so many deployment issues it's ridiculous. Most of the time I don't care what version of gems are used, just want to use the latest one.

UPDATE in response to comments:

Here are a couple of examples off the top of my head:

1. developer A is using a pre-release of a gem so when he runs 'bundle update', the Gemfile.lock is messed up for everyone else and if you deploy it, there goes your site.
2. A bug in a gem gets fixed so we run gem update across our servers, restart rails and yay, bug fixed! Oh, but wait, it's not fixed?  Thanks bundler. What should have been an easy fix is now a full code deploy across our servers.

That's just a couple off the top of my head. At least let us decide if we want to lock in gem versions or perhaps at least allow a range of versions for instance any 2.X version.

UPDATE 2: And yet another issue when there are windows developers on the team

Here is what's showing up in a windows Gemfile.lock:

```
nokogiri (1.4.4)
nokogiri (1.4.4-x86-mingw32)
```

Wow, this is just awesome. Sure makes for easy teamwork and deployment.

Comment: You're free to just require stuff as you like, **but don't**. Learn to use and like bundler and you'll be much happier in the long run. Using the latest version of a gem is fine for development, but for production -- unless perhaps you are the only one using the site -- you can and should care what version you are using. Using the latest, whatever it happens to be, is a recipe for subtle breakage.

Comment: What issues are you having with it? You don't have to specify versions; bundler is good at resolving versioning conflicts that "just install the latest" would otherwise cause. RVM + gemsets + bundler is fairly bulletproof as far as deployment goes, in my experience.

Comment: Bundler is the opposite of annoying. You can go get some coffee when you run it.

Comment: Bundler rocks. If you don't like it you are using it wrong.

Comment: @fivetwentysix I do like that it gives you time to get coffee whenever you run it. ;)

Comment: "At least allow a range of versions for instance any 2.X version": gem "annotate", "~> 2"

Comment: More docs here: http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html

Comment: Running cygwin is a good solution as far as the windows/nokogiri example goes (a problem I personally encountered)

Comment: I'm with you -- bundler is a piece of s#1t.  It needs to die in a fire.

Comment: Life sucked before bundler, and it sucks after.  Wish there were some real answers about removing it from rails.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend starting to use two techniques with your development and deployment:

**Specify version number of gems in your gemfile.**

For example:

```
gem "rails", "3.0.1"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2"
```

This way, when you decide you want to update rails, or will_paginate, change the version numbers in your gemfile.

**Only update certain gems**

Rather than the generic `bundler update` command, run

```
bundler update rails
```

This will only update the rails gem to the newest version, rather than get the latest of all gems.

If you use both 1 & 2, you'll have a happier experience.

Comment: Won't that still lock in the version though in Gemfile.lock? Which means it wouldn't help with either of my scenarios.

Comment: It helps in both scenarios. You only update explicitly when you need to, to the version you want.

Answer (score 0):

Then, simply, don't check your `Gemfile.lock` into source control. All of the specific problems you listed are solved.

Of course, you are sacrificing the enormous advantage that Bundler gives you over any other dependencies management system.